# Does System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer escape excess xml element?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Basically, I have a class that can retrieve user input from a series of textBox's that are within my program that later gets serialized for saving. If for some reason the user decides to add something like:

```
<element></element>
```

Will `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` escape that, or will I have to handle this myself?

Comment: No you don't have to handle it. But best answer would be: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Like L.B. said... I didn't read the question properly... removed my answer.